# Hide port number in URL odoo?

Tags: nginx, odoo, port, reverse-proxy, odoo-8

I need to hind port number from url. i am running odoo instance using --db-filter='^%d@', mydomain.com:8069 is works fine but mydomain.com is getting page not found. I have installed nginx and edited `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` as below.

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;

}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    # anything written in /opt/nginx/conf/mime.types is interpreted as if written inside the http { } block

    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    #

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;


keepalive_timeout  65;


server {
    # You would want to make a separate file with its own server block for each virtual domain
    # on your server and then include them.

    listen       8069;
    listen       192.168.1.111:8080;
    listen       192.168.1.111;
    #tells Nginx the hostname and the TCP port where it should listen for HTTP connections.
    # listen 80; is equivalent to listen *:80;

#server_name  localhost;
     server_name  mydomain.com;
     server_name  www.mydomain.com;
    # lets you doname-based virtual hosting

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        #The location setting lets you configure how nginx responds to requests for resources within the server.
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }


}
}
```

How can i do that? suggest any solutions..

Comment: You need to make you application accessible from a default port. Port 80 for HTTP and port 443 from HTTPS.

Comment: Could expalin how can i do that.. which file i edit?

Comment: You want apache/nginx to receive port 80 and redirect to port 8069. If you look into running odoo with a reverse proxy (GOOGLE) you will find it. Here is a discussion on the matter. There are many. https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/nginx-reverse-proxy-on-80-443-32052

Answer (score 1):

Try the following server configuration. You can put it in a separate file and include it in the main `nginx.conf` if you like.

```
upstream odoo {
   server 127.0.0.1:8080;  # Or wherever your Odoo service is listening
}

server {
    server_name mydomain.com;
    listen       0.0.0.0:80;

    root /var/www/html/odoo/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @odoo;
    }

    location @odoo {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://odoo;
    }
}
```

In short, this defines an upstream server odoo for your odoo service. When a request is received (say `mydomain.com/path/to/resource`), nginx will try to process it by delivering the corresponding resource it is supposed to serve from the root dir. If that fails, it will retry, appending a slash to it. If that fails as well, it will send the path to the upstream server (odoo) for processing.